# How to create Jar file from android library project with resources?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I want to create a Jar file of my android library project. My project contains resources like layouts, Strings and Drawbles. i created Jar file and its working but when i tried to open custom dialog from my jar file it will give error.

```
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1033)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2179)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:872)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:471)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at com.example.inappcarrierbilling.customDailog.DirectBillingDialog.onCreate(DirectBillingDialog.java:46)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:355)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:260)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at com.example.inappcarrierbilling.objects.BillingParams$2.onPostExecute(BillingParams.java:318)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at com.example.inappcarrierbilling.objects.BillingParams$2.onPostExecute(BillingParams.java:1)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-19 15:40:13.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27766):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I dont want to put may library resources in my code project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is

Build your project then copy the jar from bin (for this your project should be a library project)

Comment: this will work if i only have the code not the resource but this ans also help me out. so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Jar files cannot include resources like layouts, drawables and strings. You have to link the library as a library project to your non-library project.

First make sure your [library project is marked as library](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject), then import the library using the steps from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject).

Comment: ok thank you for the information but some of library use the resource like text2pay library and other also than the question is how they will use resources ?

Comment: I don't know that library but I can ensure you that Android jars cannot contain resources. That's the reason why some android support libraries have to be imported as library projects, not as jars.

Comment: you are right jar cannot include resource file i just copy my all resource to client code and its working thank you...